# Running Kubernetes Minikube service giving me "cannot open browser" errors

Tags: kubernetes, fedora, kubectl, minikube

I follow [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-kubernetes-in-under-3-hours-a-detailed-guide-to-orchestrating-containers-114ff420e882) tutorial about Kubernetes.

I got to the part, which guide me to run:

```
minikube service sa-frontend-lb
```

(I used sudo to run it, because if I don't use sudo it ask me to use sudo).

I get those following errors:

```
Opening kubernetes service default/sa-frontend-lb in default browser...
No protocol specified
No protocol specified

(firefox:4538): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:07:38.395: cannot open display: :0
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: x-www-browser: command not found
No protocol specified
No protocol specified

(firefox:4633): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:07:39.112: cannot open display: :0
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: iceweasel: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: seamonkey: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: mozilla: command not found
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: 
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: konqueror: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: chromium: command not found
[4749:4749:0805/220740.485576:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(88)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
[4757:4757:0805/220740.725100:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: www-browser: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: links2: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: elinks: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: links: command not found
```

I installed chromium and xdg-utils, but neither works.

How can I enter to the service, to see that it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As one can see, it *is* attempting to launch a browser, but there are none installed that it recognizes, except for what I would *guess* is Chrome *(since one can see that "chromium" did not work out)*, and as the message indicates, it doesn't tolerate running as `root`.

In that case, what you want is actually:

```
minikube service --url sa-frontend-lb
```

which causes `minikube` to *print* the URL rather than attempting to use [xdg-open](https://github.com/pkg/browser/blob/master/browser_linux.go#L4) to launch a browser.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, the format is "minikube service sa-frontend-lb --url"

Comment: My apologies, I was just working off the [syntax on their README](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/tree/v0.28.2#services) as well as the output of `minikube service --help`